# How to smooth a shaded relief map created with the command r.relief in GRASS 7?

Tags: grass-gis

How can I smooth a shaded relief map created with the command r.relief in GRASS 7?

I read about the plugin r.denoise but I can only find it for GRASS 6...

Comment: Two possibilites come to mind: `r.samp.rst` is designed to resample and smooth a raster. If you leave the resolution as the original, then it will just smooth. Also a simple `r.neighbors` might also serve your purpose.